# How to Convert Date String to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, datetime

I have Date String and want to convert it into Java.util.OffSetDateTime

Tried below code but getting exception DateTimeParseException.

```
String ts="2020-06-01T13:46:45.641956";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse(ts, fmt);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Be careful with your tags. This Question has nothing to do with Spring, nor `java.until.Date` class.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use the appropriate  class. And, omit the formatter.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-06-01T13:46:45.641956" )
```

See this code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/cAkbeq).

## Details

No need to specify a formatting pattern.

Your input happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The *java.time* classes default to those standard formats when parsing or generating text.

But you are using the wrong class for your input. Your input lacks any indication of an offset-from-UTC. So you cannot parse as an `OffsetDateTime`. Instead, use `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-06-01T13:46:45.641956" ) ;
```